# How to get the latest release number of the same version of the package in yum?

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos, yum

I am trying to get the latest release number of the package and not the latest version from the repo.

For example

```
yum --showduplicates list package

Installed Packages
package                    2.1.0-1 
Available Packages
package                    2.1.0-1
package                    2.1.0-2
package                    3.1.0-1
```

I want to update the existing `package` to `2.1.0-2` and not to the latest `3.1.0-1`. The `yum update` always try to update to the latest `3.1.0-1`. I am writing a script that checks if the release number (in this case `2.1.0-2`) is higher than `2.1.0-1` and update to that version.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the version you want to install:

```
sudo yum install package-2.1.0-2
```

Comment: Thank you but that requires the script to know the version `2.1.0-2`. The problem is there a way to upgrade to the latest ( it could be `2.1.0-4` ) if available. For your solution we need to first find out `2.1.0-2` is the latest.

Comment: Maybe you could make your question a little more clear. From the way it's currently written I'm not sure what step you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question :)

The first thing would be to get the base version (without release) of the currently installed package. You can do this by querying `rpm`:

```
VER=$(rpm -q --queryformat "%{VERSION}" foo)
```

Next, you just install that version with wildcard set for release:

```
yum install foo-${VER}-*
```

One-liner:

```
yum install foo-$(rpm -q --queryformat "%{VERSION}" foo)-*
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved this problem.